# Azure Pipelines - Multi-repo checkout return does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my pipeline a need checkout a extra repository.

I tried two styles:

- checkout: git://infra/configs-templates-deployment@main
- checkout: configs-templates # ref to resources

I approved the pipeline alert with permissions request !
But i get this error:

```
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier configs-templates-deployment does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/ORGIDXXXXX/infra/_git/configs-templates-deployment/' not found
```

If i try to clone this same URL on my PC , this works !!
The repository is in same ORGID.

Pipeline:

````
    trigger:
    - master
    - main
    - dev
    - stagging
    
    resources:
      repositories: 
        - repository: external-configs # Local variable name
          name: infra/configs-templates-azurepipelines
          type: git
          ref: main 
          # endpoint: configs-templates-deployment-connection # Azure DevOps service connection name (for external repository)
    
    stages:
    - stage: Prepare
      displayName: Prepare
      jobs:
      - job: Prepare 
        displayName: Prepare
        steps: 
        - script: echo ">>>> $(Build.Repository.Name) - $(Build.SourceBranchName) - $(EXTERNAL-VARIABLE)"
        - checkout: git://infra/configs-templates-deployment@main
          clean: true
 ```yaml
````

Comment: The strange is that I can use the pipeline templates feature, but I can't checkout
( Eg.: - template: java/build.yml@external-configs  works)

Answer (score 0):

I need use a shell script to work

```
- script: git clone https://USR:PAT@dev.azure.com/ORGID/infra/_git/configs-templates-deployment
```